# Relationships between entities in an MVC domain model

Tags: oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, orm, model

I have a web MVC application consisting of three layers, separated from each other:

- A UI layer: consists of controllers, presenters, views, etc;
- A domain model: a layer containing entities (domain objects) and database abstractions (repository interfaces - as [Separated Interfaces](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html)),
- A persistence layer: consisting of repository implementations - as [Gateways](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html).

In its definition of [Domain Model](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html), Martin Fowler says:

> A Domain Model creates a web of **interconnected objects**, where each object represents some meaningful individual, [...].

He also presents a database in the image preceding his description.

Personally, because in my persistence layer I am not using any ORM, ActiveRecord, or similar implementations, I can't imagine that I need some kind of relational mapping between the entities and the database structure - including here the relationships between the database tables too.

But then, do I still need to construct any relationships between the entities? In other words, do I need to interconnect them, like: *A `Question` entity contains a list of `Comment` entities*?

If yes, could you please explain to me, what the purpose of this "interconnectivity" could, or should be?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**

A new thought: The entities contain behaviour, executed on their encapsulated data. This behaviour, relative **only to their own data**, makes me think: What sense is there to have a `Question` entity containing a list of `Comment` entities, if the behaviour of `Question` is related only to itself? Am I maybe missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'interconnectivity' provides a way of expressing the reality of the relationship between real things in a code-based model. Once these relationships are established, and it's done well, the model becomes self-documenting and intuitive to use. Furthermore, the relationship and the related data can be controlled in/by code, protecting the state of the model and providing feedback regarding this state.

If you're reading and writing data directly to and from simple objects, then this approach could be over-complicated and unnecessary. It's worth bearing in mind that, if this is how your solution is architected, you don't really have a domain model. You just have a command/query layer and some DTOs.

Comment: Thank you, David.

Comment: David, I brought my prior comment as an "Edit" into my original question.

Comment: Sure. Have you read anything about DDD and designing aggregate roots? I say this as this approach would only have aggregate roots related by ids, supporting your idea of the question not having a related collection of comments. You could have each comment just with the id of its parent. Whether this design is appropriate is a bigger question.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, though it's planed as the next big task. But I almost understand what you're saying. So, in terms of DDD, the interconnection is very important, even in absence of any external systems which could impose it, if present?

Comment: Well, from a DDD perspective, the relationship and its relationship with the boundary of the aggregate root influences behaviour. For example, if the parent is an AR and has a collection of entities that are not ARs, then deleting the parent should also delete it's related entities.

Comment: This is indeed a good argument. Thank you again. I needed to know, so I can decide the structure of my project properly. I will try to study DDD as soon as possible. Good luck.